# If $\sin A+\cos A=m$ and $\sin^3 A + \cos^3 A=n$ then

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\sin A+\cos A=m$ and $\sin^3 A + \cos^3 A=n$ then which of the following is true?

$1$. $m^3+3m+2n=0$

$2$. $m^3-3n+2n=0$

$3$. $n^3-3n+2m=0$

$4$. $m^3-3m+n=0$

My Attempt:
$$\sin A+\cos A=m$$
And,
$$\sin^3 A+ \cos^3 A=n$$
$$(\sin A+\cos A)^3-3\sin A.\cos A(\sin A+\cos A)=n$$
$$m^3-3m\sin A.\cos A=n$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: So what does $sin^2(A)+cos^2(A)$ equate to?

Comment: A different approach would be to substitute for $m,n$ in the four multiple choice questions and see which choice is true.

Comment: @Sentinel135, $1$. But, where and How should I use it?

Comment: My direction would be similar to Uddeshya Singh's one.

Comment: Is #2 a misprint?  I think it might be $-3m$ instead of $-3n$ for the middle, otherwise it would be $m^3 - n = 0$.

Comment: @bjcolby15, I got these options in a test. so here none of them are correct!

Comment: @Maxwell Doublecheck that one of them (maybe the second one)  isn't $m^3-3\color{red}{m}+2n=0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv, No. The options are $100%$ accurate as given in the question paper.

Comment: @Maxwell Then the paper had a typo, since $m^3-3\color{red}{m}+2n=0\,$ *is* the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:$$(\sin A+\cos A)(1-\sin A\cos A)=n $$
$$m(1-\sin A\cos A)=n$$
By: $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$$

And $$(\sin A+ \cos A)^2=1+2\sin A.\cos A=m^2$$
$$\sin A.\cos A=\frac{1}{2}(m^2-1)$$

Got your option now?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $m^2 = 1 + 2 \sin A \cos A\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a multiple choice question, consider when $\sin(A)=1$ and $\cos(A)=0$. Then $m=n=1$, and this is incompatible with choices (1) and (4).

Then consider when $\sin(A)=\cos(A)=\sqrt{2}/2$. Then $m=\sqrt{2}$ and $n=\sqrt{2}/2$. This is incompatible with (2) and (3).

So none of these are correct. Is there a typo in the options you have presented?

---

If item (2) read $m^3-3m+2n=0$, it is a correct identity. And it does seem strange you presented an option that has some like terms in it.

Comment: I presented what I got in the question.

Comment: OK, well then you had a question with no correct choices. The other two answers posted here do not appear to have followed through to the end. They have not recognized that there are no correct choices among the four choices, even if their general method is sound.

Comment: `They have not recognized that there are no correct choices` That's precisely why I upvoted your answer. Plus, for a multiple choice question, yours is probably the quickest shortcut.